# ¿Como aumentar el tamaño de una imagen usando mouseOver y que se sobreponga a un conjunto de datos sin moverlos?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net

tengo una duda lo que pasa es que estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo que la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En pocas palabras al pasar con el mouse la imagen que se agrande esta (ese código ya lo hice), pero al querer visualizarlo a la derecha se mueven todos los datos que tengo a la derecha, mientras que en la foto al ver cualquier foto solo se sobrepone a los datos por delante. 
Este es el código que estoy haciendo, no sé si este bien. Gracias

```html
    <div><!--Caja contenedora-->

          <div style="float:left"><!--Col1-->              
              <% If (dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(26).ToString = "V") Then
                      Dim vImagenPortada1 As String = "INDICE/LIBROS/1Portadas_jpg/" & dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(0) & ".jpg"
                      Dim vImagenPortada As String = "imagenes/2018/imgLibro_Disponible.jpg"%>
              <div>
                  <img src='<%=vImagenPortada1 %>' alt='No tiene índice' style='height: 200px; width: 150px' />
                  <img id="imgZoom1" width="100" height="125" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="Imagenes/2019/3021.jpg"/>
              </div>
              <%ElseIf (dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(26).ToString = "P") Then
                      Dim vImagenPortada1 As String = "INDICE/LIBROS/9999_sinportada.jpg"
                      Dim vImagenPortada As String = "imagenes/2018/imgLibro_Prestado.jpg"%>
              <div>
                  <img src='<%=vImagenPortada1 %>' alt='No tiene índice' style='height: 200px; width: 150px' />
                  <img id="imgZoom2" width="100" height="125" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="Imagenes/2019/3021.jpg"/>
              </div>
              
                  <%ElseIf (dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(26).ToString = "R") Then
                          Dim vImagenPortada1 As String = "INDICE/LIBROS/9999_sinportada.jpg"
                          Dim vImagenPortada As String = "imagenes/2018/imgLibro_yaReservado.jpg"%>
              <div>
                  <img src='<%=vImagenPortada1 %>' alt='No tiene índice' style='height: 200px; width: 150px' />
                  <img id="imgZoom3" width="100" height="125" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)" onmouseout="zoomOut()" src="Imagenes/2019/3021.jpg"/>
              </div>             
              <% End If%>
            </div>
          <div>
              <div>
                  <!--Col2-->
                  <div>Título</div>
                  <div>Autor</div>
                  <div>Edición</div>
                  <div>Datos de Publicación</div>
                  <div>Páginas</div>
              </div>

              <div>
                  <!--Col3-->
                  <div><%=dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(3).ToString() %></div>
                  <div><%=dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(7).ToString() %></div>
                  <div><%=dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(6).ToString() %></div>
                  <div><%=dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(12).ToString() %></div>
                  <div><%=dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(30).ToString() %></div>
                  <div><%=dt2.Rows(i).ItemArray(0).ToString() %></div>
              </div>
          </div>

          <div><!--Col4-->
              <div id="overlay" onmousemove="zoomIn(event)"></div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt0KC.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo creo que la solución que buscas la podrías conseguir más fácil manipulando el hover mediante el css ya que podrías establecer un z-index para la sobreponer la imagen y para el efecto de aumentar la imagen puedes hacer un hover en el css ejemplo:

```
#idImagen:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: .2s;
        z-index: 1000;
}
```

espero haberte ayudado.